# Calculate MAPE on rows by groups

Tags: r, statistics, grouping

I have run an OLS regression on a dataset of housing prices. I've calculated the error for each house versus the predicted values. I have a column in the dataframe with the towns that each house belongs to. I want to calculate the MAPE for each town. My dataframe looks something like this:

```
HomePr   Error      Town 

1390      0.40093  Clarkvile   
2010      0.348902 Petersburg  
2393      0.348902 Petersburg  
2000      0.348902 Clarkvile  
7030      0.348902 Pleasant Place  
4025      0.348902 Petersburg  
4000      0.348902 Millerstown 
2086      0.348902 Pleasant Place  
6058      0.348902 Schneider  
2000      0.348902 Jebtown
```

I want to calculate MAPE by `Town`. So my first step is to get a list of the unique `Towns` and then calculate MAPE using all the `Errors` that share that group. Then I want a new column `DF$Mape` that will give me the MAPE using the houses only within each group of `Town`.

I am unsure how to go about this. Looking for suggestions.

Comment: Assuming HomePr is the actual value, then do `tapply(X = df$Error/df$HomePr, INDEX = df$Town, mean)`

Comment: You should check out the dplyr package. You can group_by(Town), and then mutate(Mape = HomePr * Error) or whatever formula you'll use. Check out a dplyr cheat sheet here: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: @Vlo this looks great actually but is there a way to attach this to the df as a new column?

Comment: `x <- tapply(X = df$Error/df$HomePr, INDEX = df$Town, mean); merge(df, data.frame(Town = names(x), MAPE = x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr); library(tibble)

mape <- function(actual, forecasted){
  x = 0.1*((actual - forecasted)/actual)*100
  return(x)
}
tibble(
  HomePr = c(1390, 2010, 2393, 2000, 7030, 4025, 4000,
             2086, 6058, 2000),
  Error = c(0.40093, 0.348902, 0.348902, 0.348902, 0.348902,
            0.348902, 0.348902, 0.348902, 0.348902, 0.348902),
  Town = c("Clarkvile", "Petersburg", "Petersburg", "Clarkvile",  
           "Pleasant Place", "Petersburg", "Millerstown", "Pleasant Place",
           "Schneider", "Jebtown")
) %>% 
  group_by(Town) %>% 
  summarise(means_pr = mean(HomePr),
            means_err = mean(Error)) %>% 
  mutate(Mape = mape(means_pr, means_err))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
            Town means_pr means_err     Mape
           <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1      Clarkvile 1695.000  0.374916 9.997788
2        Jebtown 2000.000  0.348902 9.998255
3    Millerstown 4000.000  0.348902 9.999128
4     Petersburg 2809.333  0.348902 9.998758
5 Pleasant Place 4558.000  0.348902 9.999235
6      Schneider 6058.000  0.348902 9.999424
```

*Update:* as per the comments below, the (real) dataset had `Town`as a factor. This can be converted to character simply, with `df <- df %>% mutate(Town = as.character(Town)`, where `df`is the dataframe.

Comment: this dataset listed on the original question is a sample. the actual dataframe has around 20,000 rows and around 100 Towns. instead of using a written out list how can I have r read the rows and do calculations based on that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "written out list". If you have variables like in the example above, the same code should work for the bigger dataset. What happens when you try this code?

Comment: Hi, what I mean is that you have this line: `Town = c("Clarkvile", "Petersburg", "Petersburg", "Clarkvile",  
           "Pleasant Place", "Petersburg", "Millerstown", "Pleasant Place",
           "Schneider", "Jebtown")` whereas, I have over 100 town names and all of them are recurring, perhaps each close to 100 times so writing them out the way you have is not feasible. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought you meant that. I was just making a reproducible example. For your dataset, all you need is the function to calculate the MAPE, then you use `group_by()`, `summarise()` and `mutate()` as above, it should work the same.

Comment: So I used the mape function and then group by, summarise and mutate lines. Got this error: `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"` assuming `Error`, `Town` and `HomePr` refer to  `df$Error`, `df$Town` and `df$HomePr` respectively. I neglected the middle code the `tibble()` section like you said

Comment: The `tibble()`part is just to create the dataframe. Is your dataset a dataframe? If so, the logic of the answer should work: `group_by(Town)` then summarise by taking the mean of the actual price and the error in each group, and then `mutate()` with the MAPE function. You should simplify your data as much as possible, and perhaps edit your question to include a sample of it and a reproducible problem you're having.

Comment: Okay this seems to have worked however the Town names aren't printing out. Instead it's just numbers. Maybe this has to do with the format? I'm not sure. When I  do `str(df)` I get ` $ Town      : Factor w/ 119 levels "","ALLENVILLE_PLACE",..: 43 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 ...`
Also, How do I view this `tibble` in its entirety? Thanks

Comment: They are printing as numbers because thay are factors (see https://www.r-bloggers.com/data-types-part-3-factors/). You can change them to character vectors with `mutate(Town = as.character(Town))`. I'm happy it worked -- would you like to mark the question as answered? (As for seeing the tibble in its entirety, tibbles don't allow that to avoid freezing R. You could try the Viewer pane in RStudio or change it to a plain data.frame.)

Comment: Sure but before would you like to update your answer with the `mutate(Town = as.character(Town))` line? Thanks